# How do I check if a file contains a string (using Nant)?

Tags: nant

At the moment I'm calling findstr and storing the output in a property to check afterwards - I'm sure there must be a better solution.

```
<exec program="findstr.exe"
    workingdir="${workspaceDir}"
    commandline='/i /c:"someText" ${fileName}'
    failonerror="false"
    output="${coverageExcludeLog}"
    resultproperty="foundFile"
/>
```

Is this really the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<loadfile file="${fileName}" property="MyFileContents" />

<property name="Mystring" value="someText" />

<property name="search.file" value="${string::contains(MyFileContents, Mystring)}" />
 <if test="${bool::parse(search.file)}" > <!-- true or false-->
  <echo message="Found the  string ${Mystring} in the file ${fileName}" />
 </if>
```